# Exercise on endomorphisms - proof explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an exercise about an endomorphism to solve. However I do not understand the proof for it.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and let $f$ be an endomorphism of $V$ such that $f \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_V$ .

Let $E_{1} = \{v ∈ V | f(v) = v\}$ and $E_{−1} = \{v | f(v) = −v\}$.

Show that $E_{1} = $Im$(f + \operatorname{Id}_V )$ and $E_{−1} = $Im$(f − \operatorname{Id}_V)$.

Proof:

If $v \in E_1$, then $f(v) = v$

Therefore $v = \frac1{2}v+\frac1{2}v = \frac1{2}v + \frac1{2}f(v)=\frac1{2}v+f(\frac1{2}v)$

$= (f+\operatorname{Id}_V)(\frac1{2}v) \in  \operatorname{Im} (f + \operatorname{Id}_V )$

The same steps work for $E_{-1}$. Now I do understand that they split up $v$ in two fractions but do not understand how $(\frac1{2}v+f)=(f + \operatorname{Id}_V )$

Is there some information I'm missing?

Comment: Your last equality makes no sense, because in the left part of this equality you add a homomorphism to a vector. So it is not quite clear what exactly you do not understand. In addition, you have missed the check for inclusions $\operatorname{Im}(f+\operatorname{Id}_V)\subset E_1$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f-\operatorname{Id}_V)\subset E_{-1}$.

Comment: @kabenyuk I was wondering how we get $\frac1{2}v+f(\frac1{2}v)= (f+$Id$_V)(\frac1{2}v)$ in the proof.

Comment: This is the rule of addition of homomorphisms: $x+f(x)=\operatorname{Id}_V(x)+f(x)=(\operatorname{Id}_V+f)(x)$.

Comment: @kabenyuk I see thanks. Would there not be an additional 1/2 though?

Comment: My $x=1/2v$. Where else could there be $1/2$?

Comment: @kabenyuk Thanks for your help. Apologies for my confusion, I just understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity map ${\rm Id}_V$ and $f$ are added and evaluated at $\frac12v$.

We get
$$({\rm Id}_V+f)(\frac12v)={\rm Id}_V(\frac12v)+f(\frac12v)=\frac12v+f(\frac12v)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I do not know what I my thoughts were. Of course this works. Apologies for the confusion